# Loop Adding New Column for Each Letter of the Alphabet

Tags: python, pandas

I have this simple looking issue but can for the love the almighty not figure out how to solve it.

I have a data frame that has a column with strings. I can apply the code below to add a new column that shows how often the letter "a" occurs in the string next to it. Using a loop, I can do this with every word in the column.

What I want to do now is do the same thing for every letter in the alphabet by integrating my loop into another loop. So the end result should be a data frame with one column for each letter that shows the occurence of that letter in the string.

Loops inside loops really confuse me and while I can picture how it should work in theory, I have a hard time getting it to work in practice. :(

Thank you so much!

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["fancy","nice","aweseome","wow"])
A = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    A.append(df.iloc[:, 0][i].count("a"))
df["A"] = A
df
```

---

**EDIT:**

Hey again friends, now I would like to apply the solution to as many string columns as there are in the df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["fancy", "cold"], ["nice","sunny"],["awesome", "warm"], ["wow", "rainy"]])

print(df)

for i in range(1,len(df.columns)):
    for letter in ascii_lowercase:
        df[letter] = df.iloc[:, i].apply(lambda x: x.lower().count(letter))
        df.append(df)
        
print(df)
```

My code overwrites the a-z columns from the first string column. However, I would like that it adds separate a-z columns for each string column, if that makes sense.

If this messes with the order of variables in the data frame, then it could also be a solution to store the a-z output for each column in a new data frame (either one that is appended to or one for each column). I could not really get this to work either. :/

Any help? :) THX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

for letter in ascii_lowercase:
    df[letter] = df[0].apply(lambda x: x.lower().count(letter))
```

Comment: Many good comments here that would also solve the problem and from which I can learn. So thank you so much everyone! This simple solution was sufficient for my particular problem. :) Cheers and have a great weekend!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the power of Pandas to test all rows, and put the output into a new column.  You can use chr(x) to get all letters from a-z, and get the count of the lowercase word.  For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'word': ["fancy", "nice", "awesome", "wow"]})
df['word_lowercase'] = df['word'].str.lower()

for i in range(97, 123):
    letter = chr(i)
    df[letter] = df['word_lowercase'].str.count(letter)
```

Comment: Great input! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit beyond this particular question, but perhaps it will be useful to someone else as I see frequency chart type questions like this rather often.

We can explode the strings into rows with [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas-series-explode) and [`str.upper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.upper.html), then use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to get the values counts and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back to `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["fancy", "nice", "aweseome", "wow"])
s = df[0].agg(list).explode().str.upper()
df = df.join(pd.crosstab(s.index, s))

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
          0  A  C  E  F  I  M  N  O  S  W  Y
0     fancy  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1
1      nice  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0
2  aweseome  1  0  3  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0
3       wow  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  2  0
```

---

[`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) can be used after `crosstab` to ensure all letters are present:

```
import string

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["fancy", "nice", "aweseome", "wow"])
s = df[0].agg(list).explode().str.upper()
df = df.join(pd.crosstab(s.index, s)
             .reindex(columns=list(string.ascii_uppercase),
                      fill_value=0))

print(df.to_string())
```

`df`:

```
          0  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z
0     fancy  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
1      nice  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  aweseome  1  0  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
3       wow  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0
```

Comment: Great input! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
      import string
      import pandas as pd

      # alph is a list of all letters from a-z and A-Z 
      #(uppercase and lowercase)

      alph = list(string.ascii_letters)

      '''
       ascii_lowercase  ==> for lowercase letters only
      ascii_uppercase  ==> for uppercase letters only
      '''

      '''
       num_letters is the numbers of letters from a-z and A- 
       Z which is 52
       26 lowercase letters and 26 uppercase letters
       so you do not have to worry about it being uppercase 
       or lowercase
       '''
       num_letters = len(alph)

      # this is the dataframe containing a list of the words.
      
      df = pd.DataFrame(['fancy', 'nice', 'awesome', 'wow'])

      '''
       p is the iterator to loop through alph therefore, every 
       letter  in
       the alph is known as p
      '''
     for p in alph:
        # this variable makes every letter (p) a string
          letter = str(p)

        # this sets every letter in alph to a variable which 
           # stores an empty list
          p = []

       '''
        x is used to loop through the dataframe and use 
            the len() function to establish
       '''
           for x in range(len(df)):
                   p.append(df.iloc[:, 0][x].count(letter))
           df[letter] = p

   print(df)
```

Try this
All explanations are embedded within the comments and docstrings.

This gives you control over lettering.
Its just a few lines once u remove the comments and docstrings

You can also play around with it.
I will also post another method with fewer codes

Comment: Great input! Thanks! :)

Comment: Please vote the answer up if you are satisfied with the input

Answer (score 0):

```
     import pandas as pd
     import string

     x = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
     df = pd.DataFrame(['fancy', 'nice', 'awesome', 'wow'])


     alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
     for letters in alphabet:
          df[letters] = df[0].apply(lambda x: x.upper().count(letters))
     print(df)
```

The other method I spoke of

Comment: Great input! Thanks! :)